# Append text to file without line breaking

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

On a Linux machine, I have list of IPs as follows:

```
107.6.38.55
108.171.207.62
108.171.244.138
108.171.246.87
```

I want to use some function to add the word "or" at the end of each line without breaking each line, like this:

```
107.6.38.55 or 
108.171.207.62 or
108.171.244.138 or
108.171.246.87 or
```

Every implementation I have experimented with in `sed` or `awk` has given me incorrect results as it keeps trying to line break or add input in strange spots. What is the easiest way to achieve this goal?

With `awk '$0=$0" or"'` and the `sed` suggestions I've tried thus far I get the following formatting:

```
107.6.38.55
 or 
108.171.207.62
 or 
108.171.244.138
 or
108.171.246.87
 or
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you have been trying but the following works for me on Ubuntu 12.04

```
awk '{print $0" or"}'
```

Or as [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) suggests

```
awk '$0=$0" or"'
```

Or as [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) suggests

```
awk '{print $0, "or"}'
```

[EDIT]

It turns out the OP's file had CRLF line breaks so `dos2unix` had to be run first to address the format issue

Comment: You can even put it like `awk '$0=$0" or"' file`, print is not necessary.

Comment: @fedorqui I tried your command I get issues, I edited the main post to reflect my problem.

Comment: And did you try with the first @1_CR solution? Make sure you do not have any windows character messing around.

Comment: @Trevor, what does running the command `file` on your input file give?

Comment: @fedorqui I tried solution and am having the same problem. It could possibly be a windows format problem as the file was original from a windows operating system. Is there any possibility for rectifying that formatting issue?

Comment: @fedorqui this resolved my issue and will probably resolve many other problems I am having with file markup. Marking this answer as correct since it worked after running `dos2unix` and `awk '$0=$0" or"' file`. I'm sure other solutions would work too.

Comment: Good to read that! Maybe @1_CR could include this `dos2unix` part for the future generations reading this thread :)

Answer (score 4):

The following two worked for me:

```
sed 's/.*/& or/'
sed 's/$/ or/'
```

Comment: @unxnut after resolving issues with file formatting I found that this command worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or use [ed](/questions/tagged/ed), the standard text editor:

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can use the lovely [here-strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) together with [ANSI-C quotings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

```
ed -s filename <<< $',s/.$/& or/\nwq'
```

or a pipe with `printf`

```
printf "%s\n" ',s/.$/& or/' 'wq' | ed -s filename
```

or if you like `echo` better

```
{ echo ',s/.$/& or/'; echo "wq"; } | ed -s filename
```

or interactively (if you *love* question marks):

```
$ ed filename
,s/.$/& or/
wq
```

*Remark.* I'm using the substitution `s/.$/& or/` and not `s/$/ or/` just so as not to append `or` in an empty line.